# AEM CRXDE Query widget customization

Tags: aem, crx

I need to customize the query widget in CRXDE (the one from Tools -> Query). Specifically I need to be able to add a new button to save queries into some sort of favorites as well as to load them. 
And a second button in search result widget to export the results into a excel file.
Any idea what nodes/templates are related to each widget?

Comment: which version of AEM are you on ?

Comment: @SubSul 6.1 SP2

Comment: Unlike most of other stuff in aem crxde code doesn't actually reside in jcr, but in an OSGi bundle. I guess it's possible to decompile the bundle jar and rebuild after making changes, if you really want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this interface is not designed with overlays in mind. I'd be very cautious about extending it.

While you're still using AEM 6.1, there's a lot that has been done recently about improving the visibility of [what should and what shouldn't be customized in AEM](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/sustainable-upgrades.html).

Furthermore, CRXDE is the kind of interface I really wouldn't like to break because of a bug in an overlay. It's just the kind of a low-level, last-resort UI that I like to be rock-solid.

CRXDE has remained relatively unchanged at least since AEM 5.6 but customising this particular interface could still cause you trouble at a later date when you need to upgrade. And if you're still using 6.1, it's likely that you'll be due for an upgrade to a newer version. 6.1 has [reached end of core support and extended support is only planned until 2020](https://helpx.adobe.com/support/programs/eol-matrix.html)

If I were you, I'd consider implementing a custom interface of your own. It might just be easier and you would be free to add further functionality without risking it breaking during an AEM upgrade.

Comment: yeah, totally make sense. The reason why we thought to enhance the functionality was specifically because it is so stable and upgrade (which will happen very soon) is not going to break it (too much). 
By "implementing a custom interface" do you mean adding a completely new page in AEM Web Console?

Comment: Yes, I would actually prefer to build it from scratch as a separate console of really needed. Apart from the potential to break, you may find it quite difficult to understand and extend. As far as I can tell, it's not backed by actual components sitting on the JCR and just seeing how it works may require decompiling some classes. Sounds cumbersome and it's probably against the license anyway.